# Threadpool queueuserworkitem with many threads

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli, threadpool, managed, queueuserworkitem

Heads up: I am not very familiar with working with threadpool, which might be obvious from the following code. I am under the impression that I could push many values into this queue and then it would wait for one thread to complete and then move onto the next and the system would handle the synchronization of how many threads to be running.

I am trying to use ThreadPool::QueueUserWorkItem(waitcallback, num) where the value of num is iterated up to a dynamic value depending on some prior algorithm. The problem I am coming across is the program crashes when it gets too high.

```
WaitCallback^ wcb = gcnew WaitCallBack(this, &createImage);
for(int i = 0; i < numBlocks; i++)
{
    ThreadPool::QueueUserWorkItem(wcb, i);
}
```

I get the message "Runtime Error! This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information."

My most resent run through had numBlocks = 644.

Comment: Your code called terminate().  That's typically because unmanaged code threw a C++ exception and it wasn't caught.  Nothing to do with the snippet you posted.  Be sure to debug the code with the debugger running in mixed mode.

Comment: If that is the case, it may have to do with since I am doing image conversion, prior I was running the task in a linear way and I was always able to assume the file has been closed that I am reading from. Now, I'm asking, is it possible that this type of exception could be from multiple threads trying to open the same file?

Comment: Sure, that can't work.  It doesn't require multiple threads either, you'll definitely need to improve your error handling.

Comment: I was just hoping I didn't have to modify the image reader/writer classes also. But if I must, I will.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what caused the program to crash. Most likely, an exception was thrown in one of the threads, and that brought the program down. You'll have to determine where in your code the exception was thrown.

As you know, `ThreadPool::QueueUserWorkItem` queues an item to be processed by the threadpool. But there can be multiple threads processing items from that queue. For example, you could have 20 pool threads, with 15 of them processing the work items that you queued.

If you really have that many items to process and you want them done one at a time, why not just queue one thread to do them one at a time. I've never done managed C++, so I won't try to write an example with it. But perhaps you can translate this C# code:

```
void ProcessInBackground(object state)
{
    int numBlocks = (int)state;
    for (int i = 0; i < numBlocks; ++i)
    {
        createImage(i);
    }
}
```

And then you can call it with:

```
ThreadPool::QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessInBackground, numBlocks);
```

That creates a single thread that will process the items in order.

I suspect you can convert that to managed C++ fairly easily.

Comment: I had them queued up to run 1 at a time but then the program took 4 days to complete. I need to split up the process so that it isn't as linear but instead runs multiple conversions at once (createImage(int)). I am trying to spawn and managed multiple threads of the createImage function. I could do it manually, but I thought that the QueueUserWorkItem, optimized the program based on my machine

Comment: @GeneParmesan: You should look into `Parallel.ForEach` and the Task Parallel Library. Those will do a better job of allocating threads than you can easily do with the `ThreadPool` API.